# setPlaybckSpeed() of vitamio library is not working with the videos having no voice

Tags: android

I am using vitamio library to play video at fast/slow then its original speed. `setPlaybackSpeed()` of the library works for the videos having sound but fails to work with videos having no sound.

Code which works for the videos having sound is :

```
videoSurface_view.getMediaPlayer().setPlaybackSpeed(speed);
```

where `videoSurface_view = VideoView` of Vitamio
       speed            = `Float value` to set speed of the video

Comment: Post some code, and the error thanks.

Comment: Please go through again i have mention code which works
There is no error while executing